# Asynctask JSON error handling using try and catch android

Tags: android, json, exception, android-asynctask

Im having a problem on my application, when my application refreshes or loading in slow internet connection.. the activity always destroys, or "Unfortunately (Name) is Stopped" how can i prevent the Force Close on my activity. I'm using Asynctask and JSON file to get my data out of PHP. and this is my code:

```
    package com.example.this;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActivityManager;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class Frontpane extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

            onBackPressed();
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        return;
    }

    Button Loginbutton;
    Button exitButton;

    EditText username=null;
    EditText password=null;
    EditText checker;

    String Username1;
    String Password1;

    /** For database connection**/
        private static String url = "http://1.1.1.1/radarMonitoring/api/retrieveacc.php";
        private static final String TAG_REGISTEREDACCOUNTS = "RegisteredAccounts";
        private static final String TAG_ACCNUM = "Acc_Num";
        private static final String TAG_USEREG = "User_NameReg";
        private static final String TAG_PASSREG = "Pass_WordReg";
        JSONArray accnt = null;
        String cntb;
        String cnta;
        String can;
        String cbn;
        int usncnt;
        int pswcnt;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> accntList;


     /** For database connection**/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front);
        Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Login to Continue.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
       // checker=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener(button);

        addButtonListener();
        /**array of usernames and pw **/
        accntList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        /**array of usernames and pw **/


    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    accnt = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_REGISTEREDACCOUNTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < accnt.length(); i++) {
                        int l;
                        JSONObject c = accnt.getJSONObject(i);

                       // String an = c.getString(TAG_ACCNUM);
                        String unr = c.getString(TAG_USEREG);
                       // String pwr = c.getString(TAG_PASSREG);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contac
                        HashMap<String, String> acc = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //   acc.put(TAG_ACCNUM, an);
                       acc.put(TAG_USEREG, unr);
                     //   acc.put(TAG_PASSREG, pwr);

                      if(unr.equals(Username1)){
                           usncnt = i;
                           can = unr;

                       }   
                        // adding contact to contact list
                       accntList.add(acc);



                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            } else {

               Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            cnta = can;
            if(Username1.isEmpty()==false){
                if(Password1.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Enter Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    username.setText(null, null);
                    password.setText(null, null);

                }
                else{
                    if(cnta!=null){
                    new GetPAss().execute();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Not Registered or Check your Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        username.setText(null, null);
                        password.setText(null, null);
                    }

                }
            }
            else{


                    Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Enter Username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    username.setText(null, null);
                    password.setText(null, null);

            }

        }

    }
    private class GetPAss extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    accnt = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_REGISTEREDACCOUNTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < accnt.length(); i++) {
                        int l;
                        JSONObject c = accnt.getJSONObject(i);

                       // String an = c.getString(TAG_ACCNUM);
                        //String unr = c.getString(TAG_USEREG);
                        String pwr = c.getString(TAG_PASSREG);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contac
                        HashMap<String, String> acc = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //   acc.put(TAG_ACCNUM, an);
                     //  acc.put(TAG_USEREG, unr);
                        acc.put(TAG_PASSREG, pwr);

                      if(pwr.equals(Password1)){
                           pswcnt = i;
                           cbn = pwr;

                       }   
                        // adding contact to contact list
                       accntList.add(acc);



                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog

            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */

            cntb = cbn;

            if(Username1.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Enter Username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                username.setText(null, null);
                password.setText(null, null);

            }
            else{

                /*  Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "meron", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    username.setText(null, null);
                    password.setText(null, null); */
                if(cntb!=null){
                    if((pswcnt>=0)&&(usncnt>=0)){
                        if(pswcnt==usncnt){

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Frontpane.this,MyActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                           Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            username.setText(null, null);
                            password.setText(null, null);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Username and Password does not match, Please Try Again! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            username.setText(null, null);
                            password.setText(null, null);
                        }

                    }
                }
                else{
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Wrong Password, Please Try Again! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                username.setText(null, null);
                password.setText(null, null);
                }
            }




        }

    }
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.example.RadarOperationMonitoringSystem");
                    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                    // Method 2
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                    break;
            }
        }


    };
    public void addButtonListener() {

        Loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
        Loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   Username1 = username.getText().toString();
                     Password1 = password.getText().toString();

                  new GetContacts().execute();
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Wait.. Verifying User Log-in. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }
    OnClickListener button = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Frontpane.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure want to exit?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();


        }
    };



}
```

Comment: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: logcat would be helpfull to find this bug please post it here

Comment: no toast in `doInBackground` it will crash. also post the stacktrace

Comment: UI updations like toast or any other must be done inside onPostExecute()

Comment: where can I place it?

Answer (score 1):

do this in post execute, by returning proper value from doInBackground method. All UI related code should run in ui thread.

`Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**Update**

you have to do some thing like this

```
 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            accnt = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_REGISTEREDACCOUNTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < accnt.length(); i++) {
                int l;
                JSONObject c = accnt.getJSONObject(i);

               // String an = c.getString(TAG_ACCNUM);
                String unr = c.getString(TAG_USEREG);
               // String pwr = c.getString(TAG_PASSREG);

                // tmp hashmap for single contac
                HashMap<String, String> acc = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            //   acc.put(TAG_ACCNUM, an);
               acc.put(TAG_USEREG, unr);
             //   acc.put(TAG_PASSREG, pwr);

              if(unr.equals(Username1)){
                   usncnt = i;
                   can = unr;

               }   
                // adding contact to contact list
               accntList.add(acc);



            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {

       Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        ///Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */

    if(!result)
    {
        // add here your message
        Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this,"Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    cnta = can;
    if(Username1.isEmpty()==false){
        if(Password1.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Enter Password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            username.setText(null, null);
            password.setText(null, null);

        }
        else{
            if(cnta!=null){
            new GetPAss().execute();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Not Registered or Check your Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                username.setText(null, null);
                password.setText(null, null);
            }

        }
    }
    else{


            Toast.makeText(Frontpane.this, "Please Enter Username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            username.setText(null, null);
            password.setText(null, null);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The workflow for executing asynctask is as follows

```
onPreExecute()
doInBackground(Params...)
onProgressUpdate(Progress...)
onPostExecute(Result)
```

It is possible to invoke UI code on these methods except doInBackground(Params...). The UI work should be deferred to onPostExecute(Result).

It seems that the toast message in doInbackground is triggered following an exception in the code.